# Can I bypass Apples 30% in App purchase fee?

Tags: ios

I have an app that offers certain physical courses that users follows along with. Most of these courses are free, but some we intend to take a fee for in order to attend.

Now I am confused on what rules will apply to a solution like this, can we create a payment system through for instance `Stripe` and bypass the 30% fee, or do we have to do in app purchases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> certain physical courses

As in e.g. books or other materials you send them? In that case there's no need to use IAP, and Apple won't get a cut.

If your products are digital downloads or unlocks for content, then you have to use IAP.

Comment: Material they see through the app, and then do IRL.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to use IAP

Comment: God damnit, any way to by pass it?

Answer (score 0):

> can we create a payment system through for instance Stripe and bypass the 30% fee, or do we have to do in app purchases?

**No**, **yes**.

You can't sell consumables via your iOS app and at the same time not go through Apple's InApp Purchase mechanism and bypass the 30% cut.